# В чем разница git push -u origin master и git push?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Ну вот собственно, такой простой вопрос... Создал ветку, внес изменения, добавил файлы в отслеживаемые, закомитил, смержил с веткой `master` и вот теперь хочу отправить изменения на сервер...

Как это сделать просто

```
git push
```

или

```
git push -u origin master
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Второй вариант явно показывает, куда вы пушите коммит, первый - неявно.

В большинстве случаев достаточно указать первый вариант, в крайнем случае вам появится (git 2.0 - 2.8) нотификация типа:

```
[ak@server abc]$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 367 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To abc@asdf:/asdfasddf.git
   b41acb4..b8c32bd  master -> master
```

[Цитирую](https://habrahabr.ru/post/225251/):

> Одним из самых главных изменений является поведение команды git push.
>   Теперь по умолчанию (если не указана ветка) push будет осуществлен
>   только в текущую ветку. Git 1.* по умолчанию делал push во все ветки,
>   которые были изменены локально. Конечно же можно вернуться к прежнему
>   поведению, для этого служит опция push.default.

Это очень популярный [вопрос на английском so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/), там тоже самое написано:

- `matching` означает, что `git push` отправит все ваши локальные ветки в такие же на удалённом сервере.
- `simple` означает, что `git push` отправит только текущую ветку в такую же на удалённом сервере.

Simple более интуитивный режим, поэтому он является режимом по умолчанию и используется если `push.default` не установлен.

Comment: Да я вот только, что тоже прочитал эту короткую статейку и вот не совсем понял... Пуш будет сделан только в текущую ветку, то есть если у меня 2 ветки `master и dev` и push я делаю с ветки `dev` то в `master` ничего не отобразиться? А раньше как я понял, если делал пуш то он отображался во всех ветках?

Comment: Если  у вас git1 то уйдут все измённые ветки. Если git2 то поведение зависит от режима, дополнил в посте.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде понял) Я себе поставил пока git config --global push.default simple...