# Как передать указатели (ветки) в репозиторий? git

Tags: git

Вот вопрос в том, что у меня локально есть проект в котором 3 ветки когда я делаю `push` то в репозиторий отправляется только `master`

Почему то я помню что раньше когда я создавал локальные ветки, то они тоже отправлялись в общий репозиторий с потоком отправляемых изменений.

Насколько я понимаю я могу воспользоваться командой

```
git push -u origin branch
```

но насколько я понимаю эта команда создаст ветки удалено и потом нужно будет их удалять, так как если удалить их локально в репозитории они все равно останутся.

Что делать?

Comment: Не очень ясен вопрос. Вы хотите сохранить ветки в удалённую репу и при этом не хотите их оттуда потом удалять хотя это и требуется?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб )) ну да согласен запутанно получилось, в общем мне так кажется, что когда делается пуш то ветки тоже должны отображаться в репо и это не тоже самое , что и команда `git push -u` ... или нет? или ветки именно так и отправляются в репо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13000563/3212712), чтобы запушить сразу все ветки локальные в удалённый репозиторий надо просто не указывать к-л конкретную ветку или прямо указать что пушить надо всё:

```
git push origin
```

или

```
git push origin --all
```

Иначе, если указать к-л конкретную ветку/тэг при команде `push` то отправлена будет только он/она

```
git push origin branch1
```

Также можно отослать сразу несколько конкретных веток просто перечислив их имена так:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2
```

Comment: Мне помог именно запись с тегом -all , но она насколько я понял сделала тоже самое что и я описывал с тегом -u.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, если честно - я не знаю что делает `-u`, так что не могу сказать в чём отличие и есть ли оно)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko параметр `-u` или `--set-upstream` устанавливает долговременную связь между локальными ветками(вида `feature`) и следящими ветками (tracking branches), которым соответствуют ветки удалённого репозитория. То есть в следующий раз при `git push` автоматически пушится `feature -> origin/feature` а при `git pull` – изменения забираются из `origin/feature -> feature`.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Если вопрос в том, какие и сколько веток отправляется - то почитайте про настройки `push.default matching` и `push.default simple` - например, я как-то описывал в одном из смежных вопросов: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/543167/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-git-push-u-origin-master-%D0%B8-git-push/543173#543173

Answer (score 3):

**примечание** по поводу опции `-u` (длинная форма — `--set-upstream`) в команде `push`, т.е. чем отличается команда

```
$ git push origin ветка
```

от команды

```
$ git push -u origin ветка
```

единственное отличие в результатах выполнения этих двух команд состоит в том, что вторая команда (та, что с опцией `-u` (`--set-upstream`)), добавит в файл `config` вашего локального хранилища (т.е., в файл `.git/config`) секцию, описывающую ветку `ветка`:

```
[branch "ветка"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/ветка
```

понятно, что такая секция будет добавлена только если её до этого не было, т.е. использовать опцию `-u` (`--set-upstream`) для отдельно взятой ветки имеет смысл только один раз (повторное выполнение команды `git push -u origin ветка` не будет ничем отличаться от команды `git push origin ветка`).

смысл этой секции в том, что для ветки `ветка` указывается:

1. из какого отдалённого хранилища (в данном случае — `origin`) «подтягивать» изменения
2. из какой именно ветки этого хранилища их «подтягивать» (в данном случае — из ветки `ветка`)

---

а каковы последствия наличия такой секции?

1. визуальное последствие проявляется, например, при выполнении команды

   ```
   $ git remote show origin
   ```

   в списке веток, сконфигурированных для `git pull`, вы увидите запись и про ветку `ветка` (помимо уже сконфигурированной ветки `master`):

   ```
   ...
     Local branches configured for 'git pull':
       ветка merges with remote ветка 
       master merges with remote master
   ...
   ```
2. функциональное последствие проявится при выполении команды `git pull`, когда ветка `ветка` является текущей.

   1. если упомянутая секция отсутствует, то вы получите сообщение об ошибке примерно такого вида:

      ```
      There is no tracking information for the current branch.
      Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
      See git-pull(1) for details

          git pull <remote> <branch>

      If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

          git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> ветка
      ```
   2. если же секция присутствует, то выполнится «нормальный» `pull`.

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить в объяснение что такое `upstream`, и зачем он здесь нужен использованием `-u`.
Как я понял `upstream` это своего рода соединение между локальной веткой и той что хранится удаленно. И настройки что вы показали это конфигурация ветки соединением с удаленным репозиторием. По сути команда с ключом `-u` является своего рода конфигурационной при создании хранилища или при создании новых веток.
Правильно размышляю?

Comment: слово upstream довольно многозначное. в ответе оно присутствует лишь как часть названия опции и самостоятельного смысла не несёт. // на что влияет употрбление опции, довольно подробно написано в ответе. собственно, весь ответ дан только для объяснения её смысла.